# Developing for a specialized computer with integrated hardware

Tags: .net, usb, hid, integrated

We are looking at implementing a card-reader program for a integrated computer. The computer is a touch-screen with an embedded computer, running Windows XP, and a cardreader integrated into the screen.

The reader is a USB device, but unfortunately integrated so tightly into this screen/computer that I cannot detach it and connect it to something else.

To boot, the SDK is a pain, since it is non-existant. The SDK consists of a VB (not .NET) application which communicates with the USB device through the HID subsystem through a handful of windows api functions, and since we need this to be part of a .NET application we need to reimplement it using P/Invoke.

Thus, testing this will be a pain since I will probably have to continously copy new files onto the machine and have a ton of logging to figure out what goes wrong.

Or do I? What else can I do? Running Visual Studio on that machine will be a bigger pain than just copying the program and using logging so that's not an option, but what else? Can I remote debug this from my own machine? The machine has networking capabilities so I can reach it over the network just fine.

Any tips or advice anyone can give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [USB Over Network](http://www.fabulatech.com/usb-over-network.html) or a similar program. You can make the remote USB port appear as a virtual port on your dev machine and do your debugging locally.

Comment: This worked beyond expectations! Thanks, it will help tremendously!

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) and the [command line debuggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266458.aspx) all support remote debugging.